# getting TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple with creating datetime

Tags: python, datetime-format

I need to convert a date 2017-12-03 to the format 2017-12-03T00:00.000Z but am running into the error:

```
    TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

I am concatenating like this:

```
    start_date_formatted = start_date + "T00:00.000Z"
```

The start_date is a tuple. If I print it out it appears in the terminal as ('2017-12-03,',)

I tried using

```
    from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
```

but this creates another error.

What is the correct way to concatenate to format the date?

Comment: What's the current type of your `start_date`

Comment: if i print it out it appears in the terminal as ('2017-12-03,',) and it's a type tuple

Comment: Well, do you understand what that means? Do you *want it* to be a tuple? If so, why? If not, what do you want it to be instead? Can you think of a way to get that result? Do you understand *why it is* a tuple (i.e., where the value came from, and why that code makes a tuple)? If so, is it a fault in that code, or something that you should deal with here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very obscure way to do it, but you can change this tuple to a string, remove not needed characters and do whatever you wanted to do with it.

```
start_date = ('2017-12-03,',)
start_date = str(start_date)
start_date = start_date.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace(',', '').replace("'", '')
start_date_formatted = start_date + "T00:00.000Z"
```

**Output**

```
"2017-12-03T00:00.000Z"
```

P.S. Using `re` will look much better when replacing all these characters, just didn't think about it when I wrote this answer.

Also, this is a better way for string formatting.

```
start_date_formatted = f'{start_date}T00:00.000Z'
```